# Truncated Incorrect Double Error - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `todays_elevated_businesses_temp` (
  `idBUSINESS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `KEYWORD_TEXT` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BID_AMOUNT` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idBUSINESS`,`KEYWORD_TEXT`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `elevated_business_queue` (
  `idBUSINESS` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `KEYWORD_TEXT` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BID_AMOUNT` decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
  `NO_OF_DAYS` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `clearindia`.`todays_elevated_businesses_temp`
(`idBUSINESS`, `KEYWORD_TEXT`, `CITY`, `BID_AMOUNT`)
 Select `idBUSINESS`, `KEYWORD_TEXT`, `CITY`, `BID_AMOUNT` from (
  SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value= CONCAT(o.CITY + KEYWORD_TEXT) ,@row_num+1,1)      AS POSITION
   ,o.idBUSINESS
   ,o.KEYWORD_TEXT
   ,o.CITY
 , o.BID_AMOUNT
   ,@prev_value := CONCAT(o.CITY + o.KEYWORD_TEXT)
    FROM  elevated_business_queue o,
  (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
     ORDER BY o.`CITY`, o.`KEYWORD_TEXT`, o.`BID_AMOUNT` DESC) as temp_tab
WHERE  POSITION <11;
```

I get the following error when I run this:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'New York'
```

However, when I run the select statement alone, it works fine.

Comment: And might we maybe see what that SELECT statement returns when run on its own …?

Comment: See this thread http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63112

Comment: What is d output of  Select `idBUSINESS`, `KEYWORD_TEXT`, `CITY`, `BID_AMOUNT` from (
  SELECT  @row_num := IF(@prev_value= CONCAT(o.CITY + KEYWORD_TEXT) ,@row_num+1,1)      AS POSITION
   ,o.idBUSINESS
   ,o.KEYWORD_TEXT
   ,o.CITY
 , o.BID_AMOUNT
   ,@prev_value := CONCAT(o.CITY + o.KEYWORD_TEXT)
    FROM  elevated_business_queue o,
  (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
  (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
     ORDER BY o.`CITY`, o.`KEYWORD_TEXT`, o.`BID_AMOUNT` DESC) as temp_tab
WHERE  POSITION <11;